# Get output from ansible runner in form of json/yaml

Tags: python, ansible, ansible-runner

I am executing Ansible playbook from python via `ansible_runner`. My requirement is to enhance logs and also fetch certain event result.
Ansible playbook when executed from command line gives human readable output in form of json/yaml. But how to achieve that from ansible-runner?
I have tried `RunnerConfig`, but still I am not getting that kind of output.

When executing from ansible runner as:

```
runner = ansible_runner.Runner(config=runner_config)
```

it does not giving stdout output in yaml/json format.
I tried changing ghe value of `ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK`, but do not get the desired output. The output I am trying to get which I get while running from command line:

```
TASK [copy] ******************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [Run a script to extract data] ********************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show groups data] *************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
  - characteristics:
    - name: sourceSystem
      value: Abc
    - name: tenantId
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem [set ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS in envvars is not working. #219](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/issues/219) since 2019. [Closed without fix or workaround](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/issues/219#issuecomment-525795580).

See: [ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS in envvars is not working. #219](https://ansible-runner-role.readthedocs.io/en/latest/issues-example-219.html)